# Notice: Unidentified Index: QNo in C:\\xampp\htdocs\,

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to store variables ($q11) from SQL database($demo), but i am getting error

Notice: Unidentified Index: QNo in C:\xampp\htdocs\,......

please some one give solution for this error

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
or die(mysql_error());
$sel=mysql_select_db("demo");

$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `linuxq`  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10 ");

echo "<h4 align='Center'><u>Linux Questions</u><br></h4>";

$rows11 = mysql_fetch_array($query1);
$q11 = $rows11['QNo'];
$qus11 = $rows11['Question'];
$a = $rows11['Opt1'];
$b = $rows11['Opt2'];
$c = $rows11['Opt3'];
$d = $rows11['Opt4'];
$ans11 = $rows11['Ans'];


echo " <b>Question:-<br></b>$qus11 <br>";
echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer$q11' value = '$a'></input>$a &nbsp &nbsp"; 
echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer$q11' value = '$b'></input>$b &nbsp &nbsp"; 
echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer$q11' value = '$c'></input>$c &nbsp &nbsp "; 
echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer$q11' value = '$d'></input>$d <br><br> ";
```

Comment: use while loop to print the data, as you are fetching 10 records from database

Comment: http://siliconstation.com/how-fix-php-notice-undefined-index/

Comment: @Khushboo more an if statement if he likes just one row…

Comment: yes, he can use if statement also, for one row.

Comment: its just for one row,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway to avoid unwanted error messages in your case you should check the record count for your query by adding for example :

```
...
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `linuxq`  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10 ");
echo "<h4 align='Center'><u>Linux Questions</u><br></h4>";

if(mysql_num_rows($query1)>0) {      
  $rows11 = mysql_fetch_array($query1);
  $q11 = $rows11['QNo'];
  $qus11 = $rows11['Question'];
  $a = $rows11['Opt1'];
  $b = $rows11['Opt2'];
  $c = $rows11['Opt3'];
  $d = $rows11['Opt4'];
  $ans11 = $rows11['Ans'];

  echo " <b>Question:-<br></b>$qus11 <br>";
  echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer$q11' value = '$a'></input>$a &nbsp &nbsp"; 
  echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer$q11' value = '$b'></input>$b &nbsp &nbsp"; 
  echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer$q11' value = '$c'></input>$c &nbsp &nbsp "; 
  echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer$q11' value = '$d'></input>$d <br><br> ";
}
...
```

Moreover I suppose you have several questions in you table but i don't see any loop, maybe you forgot to post it...

Answer (score 0):

Try below :-

```
$q11 = $rows11[0]['QNo'];
$qus11 = $rows11[0]['Question'];
$a = $rows11[0]['Opt1'];
$b = $rows11[0]['Opt2'];
$c = $rows11[0]['Opt3'];
$d = $rows11[0]['Opt4'];
$ans11 = $rows11[0]['Ans'];
```

Comment: But this will also print the value